# how to derive a 3D function like z = ax + by

Tags: math, 3d

I have a 3d function like z = sin(x) + sin(y).
I would like to calculate the tangent of that function for a given (x,y) point, but i didn't found anything.
So, I have two questions :

How to calculate the derived function of a 3d function like z = ax + by?

Will the result be a function like z = ax + by?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

This question sounds like you want help doing your math homework?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: @squazz : thanks, but that's not homework, I'm simply trying to generate a terrain using GLSL with mathematics functions, and derived functions can help so much to calculate normals (I think).

Comment: @ Pang : Sorry, i was hesitating to post on this forum for that question, but I saw that there was a "math" tag, and hadn't heard about stack exchange, so... I'll remember that for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see the partial derivates

> (1) dz / dy = cos(y)
>
> (2) dz / dx = cos(x)
>
> (3) z' = (dz / dy) + (dz / dx)
>
> (1) ^ (2) ^ (3) => z' = cos(x) + cos(y)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to split functions on separate axis, but wasn't sure and couldn't understand what I was doing...